# Why does my grep -E command not work with a regex pattern containing a lookbehind?

Tags: grep, regex

I have a regex which works fine for me. I checked it on following site: https://www.regex101.com/

```
(?<=.log:)[^;]*
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I try to use it with grep. I tried to do the following thing:

```
cat foo.log | grep -E '(?<=.log:)[^;]*'
```

I know that there are matches because I created and tested my regex after this pattern. Also the -E param worked because the regex `*.*` worked fine.

Here are some sample lines from my targeted file:

```
201407010300.log:2014-07-01 03:00;10.112.64.250;2;1145439;ULC IBM
201407010100.log:2014-07-01 01:00;10.112.64.250;2;1145216;ULC IBM
201407010100.log:2014-07-01 01:00;10.112.64.250;3;968549;ULC Primeline
```

Do you have any suggestions why this doesn't work?

Comment: While of no consequence to the provided sample data, you should throw a slash in front of the dot to make it literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookaheads and lookbehinds are not part of the Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax. You need Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE) using the `-P` option.